# Combine Eclipse Juno and GlassFish server

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I am using Eclipse Juno and installed GlassFish Server 3.1.2 on Windows 7 under C:\glassfish3. Glassfish is running fine and I am able to visit the admin panel under localhost:4848/common/index.jsf. Morevoer I am able to deploy a war file and can start the application. My external GlassFish-server seems ok!

If I want to add a new Server to my Eclipse Juno environment I come to a screen where I can pick a GlassFish variant and afterwards I need to set a JRE and an Application Server Directory. I can't set a path for the Application Server Directory that my eclipse wizard lets me finish the configuration. Thanks in advance for further information!

UPDATE: I got this error message in the wizard after setting the application server directory path to `C:\glassfish3\glassfish` like it is proposed here: https://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse36/#1

`There is no valid GlassFish installation in the specified directory.  Click the Install Server button to download and install to that directory.`

Comment: I'm having the same issue; Did you figure out how to get it working?

Comment: Hi Kman, no I tried JBoss as an alternative.

Comment: having the same problem with Eclipse Luna version, one year after there is no easy and simple wait to add servers to Eclipse